# how can i display a dynamic photo in the user detail's page

Tags: jsf-2, path, primefaces, graphicimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display image from database with p:graphicImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage)

I want to display a photo from its url stored in the database , so i used  as follow

```
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{userController.photo}"/> 
                </h:panelGrid>
```

and the photo attribute is a url string that points to the photo location

```
public String getPhoto() {
   String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
   ph =ejbPhoto.find(current.getIdPhoto()); 
   System.out.println("+PHOTO +++++++++++++++"+path+"\\"+ph.getPhotoName()); 
   return path+"\\"+ph.getPhotoName();
}
```

the system.out.println shows the right path of the image but in the display page the photo is not displayed,
So any idea ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage

Answer (score 3):

First, `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` returns the current working directory. I.e. the local disk file system directory which was opened at the moment the command was given to start the server. This value is **not** guaranteed to be the same everytime the server is started. It depends on the way how the server is started. E.g. in an IDE, or in a command console, or by a service, etc.

You should absolutely not let your business logic rely on such an environmental inconsistence.

Second, the generated HTML `<img src>` has to point to an URL (a HTTP path), not to a local disk file system path. It's namely the webbrowser who has got to download the image individually by an URL like `http://example.com/contextname/images/foo.png` (and thus not the webserver who has to automagically embed them in the HTML code or so). Your current code approach would only work if the `new File("")` points to the public web content folder of the deployed webapp, which is very, very unlikely.

You should make sure that the `<img src>` points to a valid HTTP URL, exactly the one which you can copypaste in webbrowser's address bar.

---

It's unclear why you've designed it like that and what your business restrictions are, so it's not possible to post a suitable answer how to properly solve it. So here are several links showing (slight) different ways of solving this:

- [How to show the server path image to PrimeFaces p:graphicImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844869/how-to-show-the-server-path-image-to-primefaces-pgraphicimage)
- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)
- [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf)

Comment: +1 for the " You should absolutely not let your business logic rely on such an environmental inconsistence."

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. Using image URLs may expose your directory structure to anyone with `firebug` or something similar. A number of bad things can happen thus, I'm not a fan of using filepaths relating to my application server's file system if I can help it. If your implementation supports it, I'd advise you serve the images from the database using primefaces' [DynaImage](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dynamicImage.jsf)

Comment: The OP can also use dynamic images if they are stored on disk. I'm also skeptical about the security issue.

Answer (score -1):

the solution is simple and the path of the photo is under the web folder of the netbeans project (Project\build\web\photo)

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" width="50%" >
                    <p:graphicImage value="/photo/#{userController.photo}"/> 
  </h:panelGrid>
```

and in the photo get method i put :

```
public String getPhoto() {

   ph =ejbPhoto.find(current.getIdPhoto()); 
   if(ph==null) return "noPhoto.png";
   System.out.println(ph.getPhotoName()); 
   current=null;
    return ph.getPhotoName();
}
```

and the photo name includes the extension .

Comment: This may 'work' for yoy, but this is unreliable. Please see BalusC's answer.

Comment: You're going completely the wrong direction. Please stop before it's too late (you'll most certainly get bugged/fired once you bring such a major conceptual mistake into production environment).