# I cant find uploaded file in the wanted directory with jsf2

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, netbeans-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page)

I'm using primefaces to upload files to my application and it's working but I have a path problem .

I'm using netbeans IDE.

I'm storing the uploaded file under : (Project\web\WEB-INF\photo) as the following code shows :

```
 public void FileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadedFile upfile = event.getFile();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(upfile.getInputstream());
    ExternalContext extContext =
                          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    File file = new File(extContext.getRealPath
                     ("//WEB-INF//photo//" + event.getFile().getFileName()));

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while (in.available() != 0) {
        fout.write(in.read());
    }
    fout.write(bytes);
    fout.close(); .......
}
```

and this method works correctly but the uploaded file does'nt exist in the wanted directory (Project\web\WEB-INF\photo) but it's found under the build folder (Project\build\web\WEB-INF\photo) so then when i want to display the photo an error says that the photo does not exist in the directory ,

so any idea ? and why the file is stored under the build not in the wanted directory ??

Comment: In my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715697/how-can-i-display-a-dynamic-photo-in-the-user-details-page) you was also given several links which shows how to do it the right way. Please do not ignore those links.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to do it the right way :)

Comment: @BalusC I followed the answer that you presented but it's not working for me, it generated an exception not found directory  besides the 'File file = new File("/path/to/uploaded/files", filename); ' does not point the C:/ but it points the domain directory of the glassfish server (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\GF3\domain1\path\to\uploaded) (it was me who created the folder under the domain to enble the run of the application)

Comment: Apparently you did actually not prefix the path with `/`.

Comment: FileNotFoundException: \path\to\uploaded\photos\blue.png .....             so even after putting  this `     <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/photos/* dir=/path/to/uploaded/" /> ` in the glassfish-web.xml , i still get the exception :(