# display an image from absolute directory with tomcat7 and primefaces

Tags: image, tomcat, primefaces, directory

I want to get images I have saved into an absolute directory from p:graphicImage

I tested [this solution (BalusC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844869/how-to-show-the-server-path-image-to-primefaces-pgraphicimage/10844924#10844924) :

but the image doesn't appears :

here is my xhtml code :

```
<h:form prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload binding="#{upload}" mode="simple" id="monfileupload" 
                  value="#{articleMB.uploadedPicture}"/>
    <p:commandLink id="mylink" onclick="uploader();">
        <h:graphicImage id="monimage" value="/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" 
                        height="64"  width="64" binding="#{image}" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{articleMB.ajouter}" value="submit"
                     ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

and here is the config of the tomcat (in server.xml) :

```
<Context docBase="C:/images_test" path="/images" />
```

and here is the directory : 
[image]

I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tomcat 7, usage of aliases attribute will help you.

```
<Context ... aliases="/images=c:\images_test\">
```

You may more on context parameters on attributes on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html