# How to get URL of the uploaded file and use it as an attribute value?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0. I want to get the URL of a file and use it as input of another attribute. I used inputFile but I can not get the URL directly from there.

Do I have to build a managedBean?

Can anyone help me with an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to get the file path from the user PC in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

> *How to get URL of the uploaded file*

This is not how it works.

When an user uploads a file, you as being the server will be given the file content as most important information. You won't be given the URL of that file, this does not make sense (the client doesn't run a webserver or so). At most you will be given the file name as additional information and in ancient browsers with security bugs (e.g. IE<10) also the full client side disk file system path, [but this information is completely worthless to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3/3374408#3374408). You just end up with the file content and the file name.

After having retrieved the file content and the file name, [you are supposed to save it yourself in the server's disk file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223) or perhaps a SQL database, depending on the degree of searchability, maintainability and portability you're after. If you intend to be able to serve this uploaded file back on another HTTP request of a client, then you are also supposed to make sure that the particular file is afterwards available by a fullworthy URL.

[There are several ways to make a saved uploaded file available by an URL afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951). [You could create a virtual host on the folder where you're storing the uploaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844869/how-to-show-the-server-path-image-to-primefaces-pgraphicimage/10844924#10844924). [Or if creating a virtual host is not possible, or when you intend to have a bit more control over serving the file, then you could create a custom servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356). [Note that you should **absolutely not** be storing uploaded images in deploy folder with help of `getRealPath()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096).